# How to add Images to Item Variations component for Product programatically

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am using the below code to add the Images for products. Seems some thing is stopping to save the images. Any missing code here?

```
var components = new List<Component>
{

    new ItemVariationsComponent
    {
        ChildComponents = new List<Component>
        {
            new ItemVariationComponent
            {
                Id = "92604332591",
                Name = "HHHHH Viva 4-Door 34.0 Cubic Foot Refrigerator w/ Ice Maker and Wifi (Stainless)",
                Policies = new List<Policy>
                {
                    new ListPricingPolicy(new List<Money> { new Money("USD", 3029.99M), new Money("CAD", 3030.99M) })
                },
                ChildComponents = new List<Component>
                {

                    new ImagesComponent{ Images = new List<string>{ "6042064_01", "6042064_02", "6042064_03" } }
                },

            }

        },
        Name ="test"

    }
};
addedItem.Components = components;
```

Comment: can you add  mediafile ids and not 6042064_01

Comment: are you getting any errors in your log files?

Comment: It works if i add Image Sitecore item id instead of Image name. ChildComponents = new List<Component>
                                {

                                    new ImagesComponent{ Images = new List<string>{ "857eccd8-03a9-49cf-9ef7-a3168e4acb11" , "857eccd8-03a9-49cf-9ef7-a3168e4acb11" } }
                                },

Comment: I will add my comment like an answer. Please mark it as right answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Images fields on commerce keep the images field like a list of media items id i. 
So a image field in commerce raw value is like : 857eccd8-03a9-49cf-9ef7-a3168e4acb11|abceccd8-a1a9-321f-9e21-a1112dsds4acb11

You need to replace in your code ids with media files ids

```
 var components = new List<Component>
    {
      new ItemVariationsComponent
      {
        ChildComponents = new List<Component>
        {
            new ItemVariationComponent
            {
                Id = "92604332591",
                Name = "HHHHH Viva 4-Door 34.0 Cubic Foot Refrigerator w/ Ice Maker and Wifi (Stainless)",
                Policies = new List<Policy>
                {
                    new ListPricingPolicy(new List<Money> { new Money("USD", 3029.99M), new Money("CAD", 3030.99M) })
                },
                ChildComponents = new List<Component>
                {

                    new ImagesComponent{ Images = new List<string>{ "857eccd8-03a9-49cf-9ef7-a3168e4acb11" , "857eccd8-03a9-49cf-9ef7-a3168e4acb11" }}
                },

            }

        },
        Name ="test"
    }
};
addedItem.Components = components;
```